# How to compile Memgraph 2.7 on ARM / M1 (inside Docker)

Tags: memgraphdb

I 'cant get Memgraph 2.7 to compile on my Mac (M1 CPU) inside of the Docker. I can run Memgraph Platform 2.7 without any issues so I suspect that there is something with make file that I'm missing.